# Hibernate One to One Association when key names are different

Tags: hibernate, one-to-one, composite-primary-key

I have two tables with composite id having one to one relationship.

Table One : PK Columns : column1, column2 
Table Two : PK Columns : column3, column4.

Columns are having different names. I have to map column1 to column3 and column2 to column4.
Table1(PARENT TABLE) Declaration:

```
<class name="com.java.TABLE1" table="TABLE1">
        <composite-id name="TABLE1_pk" class="com.tc4.dal.TABLE1_PK">
            <key-property name="COLUMN1" column="COLUMN1" />
            <key-property name="COLUMN2" column="COLUMN3" />
        </composite-id>
...remaining properties declarations...

<one-to-one name="TABLE2" class="com.tc4.dal.TABLE2"
            cascade="save-update, delete">
             <key column="COLUMN3" property-ref="COLUMN1" />
            <key column="COLUMN4" property-ref="COLUMN2" />
</one-to-one> 
</class>
```

Table2(CHILD TABLE) Mapping

```
<class name="com.java.TABLE2" table="TABLE2">
        <composite-id name="TABLE2_pk" class="com.tc4.dal.TABLE2_PK">
            <key-property name="COLUMN3" column="COLUMN3" />
            <key-property name="COLUMN4" column="COLUMN4" />
        </composite-id>
</class>
```

while launching the application, getting following exception

```
  Caused by: org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from resource com/JAVA/TABLE1.hbm.xml
    Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The content of element type "one-to-one" must match "(meta*,formula*)".
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:196)
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:390)
```

How to give one to one association in mapping file for this case.

Regards,
Naresh.

Comment: Can you show other mapping details like how you are mapping composite id? with <composite-id class??

Comment: As per question `LNBCPRODHDRP0`  has key column name `BC_BANK_ID, BC_BRANCH_ID, BC_PRODUCT_NBR` but in your case with `LNBCPRODHDRP0_pk` is refering to `LC_BANK_ID, LC_BRANCH_ID, LC_PRODUCT_NBR` Also please edit the original question to add this information. do not give code in comments.

Comment: @ rahul maindargi, I have edited my question. Could you please check

Comment: which  version of hibernate you are using?

Comment: @ Rahul, I am using hibernate 3.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Renaming the child table composite key columns as they are in parent table has solved the issue.
Detailed Explaination :-
 - Parent Table(TABLE1):

> ```
> <class name="com.java.TABLE1" table="TABLE1">
>             <composite-id name="TABLE1_pk" class="com.tc4.dal.TABLE1_PK">
>                 <key-property name="COLUMN1Prop" column="COLUMN1" />
>                 <key-property name="COLUMN2Prop" column="COLUMN3" />
>     </composite-id>
>     .... remaining properties
>     </class>
> ```

// As TABLE1 is having composit key, need to create primary key POJO for TABLE1

```
public class TABLE1_PK {
    public String COLUMN1Prop;
    public String COLUMN2Prop;
  }
```

TABLE1 entity:

```
public class TABLE1{
  // declare PK
  private TABLE1_PK TABLE1_pk;
// getters and setters and remaining properties
}
```

- Child Table(TABLE2):

  > ```
  >  <class name="com.java.TABLE2" table="TABLE2">
  >                      <composite-id name="TABLE2_pk" class="com.tc4.dal.TABLE2_PK">
  >                          <key-property name="COLUMN1Prop" column="COLUMN3" />
  >                          <key-property name="COLUMN2Prop" column="COLUMN4" />
  >              </composite-id>
  >              .... remaining properties
  >       </class>
  > ```

Child Entity PK

```
public class TABLE2_PK{
// here property names should be defined as parent Entity properties
        public String COLUMN1Prop;
        public String COLUMN2Prop;
.. getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score 1):

with annotation u can achieve it like this.. in table 1

```
 @OneToOne(targetEntity = TABLE2.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumns(value = {
         @JoinColumn(name = "COLUMN1", referencedColumnName = "COLUMN3"),
         @JoinColumn(name = "COLUMN2", referencedColumnName = "COLUMN4") })
  TABLE2 table2
```

With XMl Try this and let me know

```
<class name="com.java.TABLE1" table="TABLE1">
        <composite-id name="TABLE1_pk" class="com.tc4.dal.TABLE1_PK">
            <key-property name="COLUMN1PROP" column="COLUMN1" />
            <key-property name="COLUMN2PROP" column="COLUMN3" />
        </composite-id>
...remaining properties declarations...

<one-to-one name="TABLE2" class="com.tc4.dal.TABLE2"
            cascade="save-update, delete">
             <key column="COLUMN1PROP" property-ref="COLUMN3PROP" />
            <key column="COLUMN2PROP" property-ref="COLUMN4PROP" />
</one-to-one> 
</class>

<class name="com.java.TABLE2" table="TABLE2">
        <composite-id name="TABLE2_pk" class="com.tc4.dal.TABLE2_PK">
            <key-property name="COLUMN3PROP" column="COLUMN3" />
            <key-property name="COLUMN4PROP" column="COLUMN4" />
        </composite-id>
</class>
```

Or

```
<class name="com.java.TABLE1" table="TABLE1">
        <composite-id name="TABLE1_pk" class="com.tc4.dal.TABLE1_PK">
            <key-property name="COLUMN1PROP" column="COLUMN1" />
            <key-property name="COLUMN2PROP" column="COLUMN3" />
        </composite-id>
...remaining properties declarations...

<one-to-one name="TABLE2" class="com.tc4.dal.TABLE2"
            cascade="save-update, delete">
             <key column="COLUMN1" property-ref="COLUMN3PROP" />
            <key column="COLUMN2" property-ref="COLUMN4PROP" />
</one-to-one> 
</class>

<class name="com.java.TABLE2" table="TABLE2">
        <composite-id name="TABLE2_pk" class="com.tc4.dal.TABLE2_PK">
            <key-property name="COLUMN3PROP" column="COLUMN3" />
            <key-property name="COLUMN4PROP" column="COLUMN4" />
        </composite-id>
</class>
```

Let me knwo which one works. :)

Comment: Hi Rahul, Thanks for your reply. I am using xml based mapping. I have tried your second case, which is still causing exception. I doubt whether your first case would work because, here column tag should refer to a column(<key column="COLUMN1PROP" property-ref="COLUMN3PROP" />)

Comment: @ rahul maindargi, any comments or any other suggestions??

Comment: well i am also searching and going through hibernate documentation. will update answer as soon as i find something:)

Comment: @ rahul maindargi, Thanks a lot

Comment: you just saved my 2 days of confusion. thanks! btw, i'm using xml mapping.. with "property-ref" as you suggested. but in my case, it's many-to-one relation, and i put "property-ref" inside <many-to-one> tag